# Setting columns to datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, datatable

This is my c# class.

```
             public class GridMetaData
             {
                   public IEnumerable<ColumnInfo> ColumnList {get;set;}
                   PageSizeList = new List<int> {10,20,50};


             }
             public class ColumnInfo
             {
                 public string Title {get;set;}   
             }
```

Here is my controller class code

```
      [Route(user/searchmetatdata)]
      public GridMetadata SearchMetaData()
       {
          return userBO.SearchMetadata(); //This gets column list from database.
       }
```

Here is my ajax call from UI client.

```
  $(ajax({
       url: 'user/searchmetadata'
       type:"GET"
       success: function(data){

             //I want here pull columns details and set to datatable. 
             .....

         };
    });
```

My ajax call returns "data" in following format

```
  data
     --ColumnList
         --[0]
             -- Title = "FirstName"
         --[1]
             -- Title = "LastName"
```

My datatable code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#employees').dataTable( {
    "ajax": // what format i should send data here?
    "columns":  // what format i should send data here?

    ]
} );
```

} );

how do i parse from above "data" response?

Do I have to write custom method to convert "data" to json?

Comment: Have you tried to loop among ColumnList?

Comment: yes, i got the values and formatted manually. but i want to know Is this the right approach?